Residue of Dirichlet series at $s = 1$
Let $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of complex numbers, and suppose that the sequence has a well-defined "average", in the sense that
$$ \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i = 1}^N a_i = R$$
for some $R$.
Does it follow that $\displaystyle \lim_{s \to 1^+} (s-1) \sum_{n \ge 1} \dfrac{a_n}{n^{s}}$ exists and is equal to $R$?
I found several sources which prove slightly stronger statements under the slightly stronger assumptions; e.g. Theorem 1 in section 2 here shows that if $\left|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i = 1}^N a_i - R\right| = O(N^{-\delta})$ for some positive $\delta$, then $\sum_{n \ge 1} a_n n^{-s}$ has meromorphic continuation to $\{s : \operatorname{Re}(s) > 1 - \delta\}$ with a simple pole of residue $R$ at $s = 1$. But I couldn't find the exact statement above.

Possibly ignorant question: do you know the result if $a_i \to R$?

Also, I think you meant "Theorem 1" instead of "Theorem 2" in your link.

No, I do not know the result if $a_i \to R$ (absent any control on the rate of convergence).

Also, you should multiply by $s-1$ instead of divide by $s-1$ in your question. I.e., $(s-1)\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{a_n}{n^s}$ is what should tend to $R$.

I think it's a standard exercise in summation by parts if I didn't make a mistake.
We wish to show $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \epsilon \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{a_n}{n^{1+\epsilon}} = R.$$
The sum is the limit as $N \to \infty$ of $$\frac{\sum_{n \le N} a_n}{N^{1+\epsilon}} + (1+\epsilon)\int_1^N \frac{\sum_{n \le t} a_n}{t^{2+\epsilon}} dt,$$
which is $$(1+\epsilon)\int_1^\infty \frac{t^{-1}\sum_{n \le t} a_n}{t^{1+\epsilon}} dt.$$
So we care about $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} (1+\epsilon)\epsilon\int_1^\infty \frac{t^{-1}\sum_{n \le t} a_n}{t^{1+\epsilon}}dt = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} (1+\epsilon)\epsilon\int_1^\infty \frac{R+o_{t \to \infty} (1)}{t^{1+\epsilon}}dt,$$ which is $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} (1+\epsilon)\epsilon\Bigl[\frac{R}{\epsilon}+ \int_1^\infty \frac{o_{t \to \infty}(1)}{t^{1+\epsilon}}dt\Bigr],$$ so we just want to show $$\epsilon\int_1^\infty \frac{o_{t \to \infty}(1)}{t^{1+\epsilon}} dt = 0.$$
Let $g(t)$ be the $o_{t \to \infty}(1)$ function. Take $C > 0$ so that $|g(t)| \le C$ for all $t$. Now, take $\alpha > 0$, and let $T$ be large enough so that $|g(t)| \le \alpha$ for all $t \ge T$. $$\Bigl|\epsilon \int_1^\infty \frac{g(t)}{t^{1+\epsilon}}dt\Bigr| \le \epsilon \Bigl[\int_1^T \frac{C}{t^{1+\epsilon}} dt + \int_T^\infty \frac{\delta}{t^{1+\epsilon}}dt\Bigr].$$ This is at most $$\epsilon C \log T + \delta.$$ By taking $\epsilon \to 0^+$, it is at most $\delta$. But $\delta > 0$ was arbitrary.

Yes, the conclusion follows. Indeed, fix any $\varepsilon>0$. For $t>0$ sufficiently large, the sum
$$S(t):=\sum_{n\leq t}a_n$$
satisfies
$$|S(t)-Rt|\leq\varepsilon t.$$ Hence for any $s>1$, the Dirichlet series
$$F(s):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n^s}=s\int_1^\infty\frac{S(t)}{t^{s+1}}\,dt$$
can be bounded as
$$\left|\frac{F(s)}{s}-\frac{R}{s-1}\right|
=\left|\int_1^\infty\frac{S(t)-Rt}{t^{s+1}}\,dt\right|
\leq\frac{\varepsilon}{s-1}+c(\varepsilon),$$
where $c(\varepsilon)>0$ is a constant. Multiplying both sides by $s(s-1)$, and letting $s$ tend to $1$ from the right, it follows that
$$\limsup_{s\to 1+}\left|(s-1)F(s)-R\right|\leq\varepsilon.$$
As $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we conclude that
$$\lim_{s\to 1+}(s-1)F(s)=R.$$
